# Calculate difference in timestamps for rows in a partition HIVE

Tags: sql, datetime, hive, hiveql, window-functions

I need to calculate the difference between the various interactions for a serial number in hive.
My table has multiple serial numbers with with multiple interactions. I have ordered the interactions for a serial number based on its timestamp. I would now also be interested in adding a column with the difference in timestamps for consecutive rows.

For example, the last column in the image shows the expected output.

[image]

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lag()` to access the "previous" row in a given partition:

```
select
    t.*,
    lag(timestamp) over(partition by sr_no order by timestamp) as lag_timestamp
from mytable t
```

Say you want the difference in seconds between the two timestamps, then:

```
select
    t.*,
    unix_timestamp(timestamp)
        - unix_timestamp(lag(timestamp) over(partition by sr_no order by timestamp)) 
        as diff_seconds
from mytable t
```

Comment: I think Hive allows you to directly subtract two timestamps and yields an interval datatype with appropriate text formatting?

Comment: @MatBailie: that would make the query neater. Do you have a doc that references this behavior? I can't find one, - and there is no Hive fiddle in the wild to used for testing.

Comment: Nope, "the" manual seems to be quite limited on the Operations that can be applied. I only have a distant memory, and this : https://sqlandhadoop.com/how-to-subtract-timestamp-date-time-in-hive/